# Redirecting airflow from window AC

Tags: air-conditioning

I want to redirect airflow from window AC. It does not have ability to direct airflow up, away from occupants; just left and right.

I was looking at floor air deflectors.

What other options would I have?

Comment: What's a "floor air deflector"? What model air conditioner? Please be more specific in your post so we can suggest good solutions rather than writing a general guide.

Comment: I doubt you will find a product engineered for this specific purpose nor for your specific air conditioner. An air deflector for HVAC registers seems like your best choice. You just have to figure out how to attach it to the window AC without damaging it.

Comment: With enough duct tape you could just build out a custom air deflector for your window AC. It might not be pretty but it will work and you don't risk damaging the AC.

Comment: Sounds like a job for MacGyver...cardboard and duct tape.

Comment: Bend a sheet of cardboard and attach to the box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a wall register deflector, that's basically what you have. This one fits 10" to 16". You could mount it by screwing it into the AC framing or with some waterproof double sided tape.

[image]

[Image source](https://www.target.com/p/deflect-o-deflecto-air-deflector-for-wall-register-clear-def51/-/A-82316162?ref=tgt_adv_XS000000&AFID=google_pla_df&fndsrc=tgtao&DFA=71700000084268426&CPNG=PLA_Appliances%2BShopping_Conquesting%7CAppliances_Ecomm_Home&adgroup=SC_Appliances&LID=700000001170770pgs&LNM=PRODUCT_GROUP&network=g&device=c&location=9011856&targetid=aud-554348707619:pla-322713572291&gclid=CjwKCAjw3MSHBhB3EiwAxcaEu2oGCmjqm7YRg_JidPSihOc16-8sZkqHaUp6znvpjxZzorUZ-upqeRoCpwcQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds)

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica  Learned that from you... and yellow wire for travelers.... and a bunch of other stuff...

Answer (score 0):

I noticed my Friedrich window air conditioner, and probably many other models, has a vent that's 17" long, which is longer than many of the advertised air conditioning air deflectors.

As a solution, I found that you can use a baseboard air deflector instead, which is adjustable from 15-25" and can be mounted on the air conditioner with double-sided tape as the previous answer suggested.